# how to integrate azure cosmosdb with databricks

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, databricks, azure-databricks

I have these following inputs.

1. Endpoint
2. Database
3. Collections

Based on these inputs needs to establish a connection with Azure Cosmos Db from databricks

Tried this approach: installed `importted com.azure.cosmos.spark` maven package in databricks cluster with the DBR of 11.3LTS and spark 3.3.0

```
readCfg = {
    "Endpoint": "<endpointurl>",
    "Database": "<dbname>",
    "Collection": "<collectionname>"
}

 

readCfg1 = {
  "spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint": "<endpointurl>",
  "spark.cosmos.database": "<dbname>",
  "spark.cosmos.container": "<collectionname>"
}

 

# Read data from Cosmos DB
df = spark.read.format("com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark").options(**readCfg).load()
df.show()
```

Error Message

```
getting class not found/assertion error
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. You can modify the query as per requirement.

```
import uuid
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
cosmosEndpoint = "https://xxxxxxxxx.documents.azure.com:443/"
cosmosMasterKey = "mxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=="

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cosmosCatalog", "com.azure.cosmos.spark.CosmosCatalog")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cosmosCatalog.spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint", cosmosEndpoint)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cosmosCatalog.spark.cosmos.accountKey", cosmosMasterKey)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cosmosCatalog.spark.cosmos.views.repositoryPath", "/viewDefinitions" + str(uuid.uuid4()))#

database1 = "<your_databasename>"
sourceContainer = "<your_container_name>"


query = """select * from cosmosCatalog.{}.{} 
""".format(database1, sourceContainer)
 
df = spark.sql(query)
df.show()
```

Comment: This isn't answering any question- it's just code

Answer (score 0):

Try the alternative below code -

```
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient

cosmosEndpoint = "xxxx"
cosmosPrimaryKey = "yyyy"
cosmosDatabaseName = "zzzz"
cosmosCollectionName = "xyz"

client = CosmosClient(cosmosEndpoint, credential=cosmosPrimaryKey)
database = client.get_database_client(cosmosDatabaseName)
collection = database.get_container_client(cosmosCollectionName)

# Enumerate the returned items
import json
for item in collection.query_items(
        query='SELECT * FROM {0} r'.format(cosmosCollectionName),
        enable_cross_partition_query=True):
    print(json.dumps(item, indent=True))
```

Comment: This isn't answering any question; it's just code